# Odata2 Filtering parent or children of different types

Tags: c#, odata

I am trying to filter nested data but the catch is, the children I am also trying to filter are of a different type.

I have data that looks like this:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "UserName": "scottketchum",
            "FirstName": "Scott",
            "LastName": "Ketchum",
            "MiddleName": null,
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Age": null,
            "Emails": [
                "Scott@example.com"
            ],
            "FavoriteFeature": "Feature1",
            "Features": [],
            "AddressInfo": [
                {
                    "Address": "2817 Milton Dr.",
                    "City": {
                        "Name": "Albuquerque",
                        "CountryRegion": "United States",
                        "Region": "NM"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "HomeAddress": null
        },
{
            "UserName": "harryingram",
            "FirstName": "Harry",
            "LastName": "Ingram",
            "MiddleName": null,
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Age": null,
            "Emails": [
                "Harry@example.com"
            ],
            "FavoriteFeature": "Feature2",
            "Features": [],
            "AddressInfo": [
                {
                    "Address": "123 Scott Ln.",
                    "City": {
                        "Name": "Nashville",
                        "CountryRegion": "United States",
                        "Region": "TN"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "HomeAddress": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to be able to type the word "Scott" in my search field and return any person that has the name "Scott" or has an Address with the word "Scott" in it. So, ideally, the search would return both people.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  void searchitemfromjson(string s)
        {
            var text = File.ReadAllText("D://jsontest.txt");
            var jObject1 = JObject.Parse(text)["value"];
            var searchs = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in jObject1)
            {
                var jObjitem = JObject.Parse(item.ToString());
                IList<string> keys = jObjitem.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                foreach (var k in keys)
                {
                    if (k == "UserName")
                    {
                        if (jObjitem[k].ToString().Contains(s)) searchs.Add(jObjitem[k].ToString());
                    }
                    else if(k == "AddressInfo")
                    {
                        if(jObjitem["AddressInfo"][0]["Address"].ToString().Contains(s)) searchs.Add(jObjitem[k].ToString()); ;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```